# Schema with embedded discriminators in arrays not cloned properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have scheme with embedded discriminators, and I want to clone it. But when I've create model from this cloned schema, and try to create document, some properties, related to this discriminators are goes away.

Here the code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const propertiesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
},
{ discriminatorKey: 'type', _id: false });

const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  properties: [propertiesSchema]
});

const propertiesArray = collectionSchema.path(`properties`);

propertiesArray.discriminator(`type1`,
 new mongoose.Schema({ type1: String }, { _id: false })
);

propertiesArray.discriminator(`type2`,
 new mongoose.Schema({ type2: String }, { _id: false })
);

const Collection = new mongoose.model('Collection', collectionSchema);
const Clone = new mongoose.model('Clone', Collection.schema.clone());

const data = {
  name: "Collection",
  properties: [
    { type: "type1", type1: "type1-1" },
    { type: "type2", type2: "type2-2" }
  ]
}


console.log(new Collection(data));
console.log(new Clone(data));
```

Result is:

```
{ _id: 5d1b583e6d2d8b519c8849b8,
  name: 'Collection',
  properties:
   [ { type: 'type1', type1: 'type1-1' },
     { type: 'type2', type2: 'type2-2' } ] }
{ _id: 5d1b583e6d2d8b519c8849b9,
  name: 'Collection',
  properties: [ { type: 'type1' }, { type: 'type2' } ] }
```

So question is - why documents are different, and how to correctly clone, or "re-apply" discriminators on cloned scheme ?

node: v10.15.3
mongoose: 5.6.2

Comment: [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-set) 'cloneSchemas': false by default. Set to true to clone() all schemas before compiling into a model.

Comment: If I set mongoose.set('cloneSchemas', true), then both documents became properties: [ { type: 'type1' }, { type: 'type2' } ] }, but I need [ { type: 'type1', type1: 'type1-1' },  { type: 'type2', type2: 'type2-2' } ]

Answer (score 0):

Issue will be fixed in version 5.6.4

[Github fix commit](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/cbc81c818206029fc75064e4fc58ddc0988231bd)